# Extract Date from string in the following format M_D_YY using patindex

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
  DECLARE @Stringval VARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @Stringval = 'Q Baltimore - Q2 2019 - System Files (6_5_19)'

  PRINT SUBSTRING(@Stringval, patindex('%[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9][0-9]%', @Stringval), 6);
```

I was expecting it to print "6-5_19" but it is printing "2 2019".
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to check is it "6_5_19" or "6-5_19" the expected result ? Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Perhaps the underscore in your pattern argument means something special?

Comment: Try to enclose in brackets the _ sign like `patindex('%[0-9][_][0-9][_][0-9][0-9]%', @Stringval), 6);` otherwise it means 'any character'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you are interested in a TVF, consider the following:

Tired of extracting strings ... charindex, patindex, left, right, ... I modified a parse function to accept two unlike delimeters.   Being a TVF, it is easy to use within a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
 DECLARE @Stringval VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Q Baltimore - Q2 2019 - System Files (6_5_19)'
 
 Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@StringVal,'System Files (',')')
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       6_5_19
```

The Function if Interested

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delim1 varchar(100),@Delim2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
          ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)-1)
    From  (
            Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                  ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
            From  ( values (convert(xml,'<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delim1,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>').query('.'))) as A(XMLData)
            Cross Apply XMLData.nodes('x') AS B(i)
          ) C1
    Where charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)>1
)
/*
Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I've oversimplified this, but just add a `(` to the patindex()

```
 DECLARE @Stringval VARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @Stringval = 'Q Baltimore - Q2 2019 - System Files (6_5_19)'

  PRINT SUBSTRING(@Stringval, patindex('%([0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9][0-9])%', @Stringval)+1, 6);
```

**Returns**

```
6_5_19
```